# How can I add actionListner to the menu (not menuitems of a menu) in the menubar.When I click the menu i want to go to other frame

Tags: java

```
private void jMenu1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
{                                       
    addcashier1 ac=new addcashier1();
    ac.setVisible(true);
    //System.out.println("add cashier");
}
```

Please suggest the corrections to be done in my code. Here 'addcashier1' is a frame that I had already made.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go to another frame the you have create another frame called frame2. And in Action listener you need to called that. Code is given below.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
    if(ae.getSource() == b1){
        Frame2 f2 = new Frame2();
        f2.setSize(400, 400);
        f2.setVisible(true);
    }
    else{
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

b1 is your menuitem and Frame2 is a new Frame

In this code we first get the source and then assign to frame.

Comment: you can use other Awt and swing examples from this link. [link](https://github.com/maddy65/JavaGraphics)

Comment: k..thnx..let me check it